# Quartz's CronTrigger for every two hours

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule a component with Quartz's CronTrigger for every two hours.
What is the correct cron expression to achieve this?

Comment: Refer to their site: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You probably want a cron expression like:

```
"0 0 0/2 * * ?"
```

Comment: How could i add every 2 hr 30 minutes and 30 seconds?

Comment: Use this - "0/30 0/30 0/2 * * ?"

Answer (score 1):

Using quartz scheduler. Following cron expression for executing job two hour.

```
String cronExpression = "0 0/120 * * * ?";
```